# ヘルプセンターにあるタグwikiの説明がよく分からない

Tags: サポート, タグwiki

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user の「タグ Wiki には何を書いたらいいですか?」には、概要として以下の点が説明されています (強調は私がつけました)。

> - 抜粋は、タグを簡潔にうまく説明するものです。
> - **タグの背後の概念を総称的に定義するのは、非常に特殊化したものの場合を除いて避けてください。**
> - コミュニティにとってタグが何を意味するかに集中してください。
> - タグをどのような場合に使用するかについての基本的なガイドラインを提示します。

この内2つ目の「タグの背後の概念を総称的に定義するのは、非常に特殊化したものの場合を除いて避けてください。」という文の意味がよく分かりません。これは具体的に何をしてほしくなくて、何をしてほしいという文なのでしょうか？

尚[英語版](http://Avoid%20generically%20defining%20the%20concept%20behind%20a%20tag,%20unless%20it%20is%20highly%20specialized.)では、

> Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized.

となっています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[What is a tag wiki? How do I write a good one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one)

上記が、該当説明に対する良い説明記事だと思います。

> Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized. The “email” tag, for example, does not need to explain what email is. I think we can safely assume most internet users know what email is; there’s no value in a boilerplate explanation of email to anyone.

ざっくり翻訳すると、

「タグの概念を、一般的な意味でもって定義することは、それ自身が高度に特殊化されていない限り、お控えください。例えば「メール」タグがあったとします。このタグは、メールが何であるかについての説明を行う必要はありません。インターネットユーザーの大半が、メール自体が何であるかについては知っているという想定をおいてしまってもいいとおもいます。メールがなんであるかを説明する決まり切った説明文をあえて書き直すことに意味はないと思います」

でしょうか。

その下の項目である、「コミュニティにとってタグが何を意味するかに集中してください。」と関連していると思っていて、例えば「チューリング完全」であるとか「np-hard」など、その単語自体が十分にプログラミング（この場合はアルゴリズムですが）について特殊化した用語であって、このコミュニティにとっての意味と、その単語の総合的な意味が一致していると思います。そのような場合には、そのままタグWikiにしてしまっても妥当だろう、ということなのではないかと思っています。